# Real world probabilities from option implied risk neutral density?

Tags: options, implied-volatility, risk-neutral-measure, probability, real-world-measure

The work of Breeden and Litzenberger-formula (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2642349) gives us a risk neutral probability distribution of a stock price, depending on the option prices.

---

**Question 1**: Is there a theoretical or practical way of obtaining real world probabilities given risk neutral ones?

**Question 2**: What does a real world probability distribution look like compared to a risk neutral, in empirical cases?

Comment: You should search for the *Ross Recovery Theorem* and the related literature on why this method does /can not work. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15099/what-are-the-main-flaws-behind-ross-recovery-theorem

Comment: This question  is directly related to your Q1 : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8274/how-to-estimate-real-world-probabilities

Comment: And this paper  also tries to answer both Q1 and Q2: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3732350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! Unfortunately, it's not easy. We can use option prices to get the $\mathbb{Q}$-distribution. However, the probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ merges the stochastic discount factor (SDF) $M$ and the real world probabilities, $\mathbb{P}$, and it's not clear how to untangle the two (see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/55251/41821)). Essentially, you have one equation, but two unknowns.

You can recover $\mathbb{P}$ if you make assumptions about the SDF $M$, see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/50701/41821) for an example (power utility). However, the asset pricing literature has many, many different models for the SDF and a misspecified $M$ gives you misspecified real world probabilities...

There is hope though. ``[Recovery theory](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/15099/41821)'' is part of current research. Famously, Steve Ross proposed a possibility in [his 2015 JF publication](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/jofi.12092). However, [Jackwerth and Menner (2020, JFE)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X20300763) cast doubt whether the recovery theorem is compatible with future realised returns and variances. So, this recovery is still being researched.

How do $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ differ? Well, the answer is the [SDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_discount_factor). You can take the simplest models (log-normal) to get a taste, see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59781/illustrating-the-change-of-measure-in-black-scholes-merton/59789#59789). Essentially, the likelihood of bad events get inflated under $\mathbb{Q}$ because these are the states with high marginal utility (= that investors fear) whereas $\mathbb{Q}$ puts less weight on good events.